# multiple requests AJAX output not rendered in IE

Tags: javascript, ajax, internet-explorer

The following (shortened) code works like an auto-complete on a input box, outputting results in a div below the input box.

It works perfectly in Chrome / Firefox (ie, search for "Eggs", and then "Milk" show their results), however in IE it makes the first request just fine, however it will not output any further requests.

The network shows that IE is making the subsequent requests to the server (200 header code), however it dosnt do anything with it.

Edit: I cannot use jQuery. But can use YUI3 (platform limitations)

```
/* Setup Ajax */
function ajaxRequest(){var activexmodes=["Msxml2.XMLHTTP", Microsoft.XMLHTTP"],i;if(window.ActiveXObject){for(i=0; i<activexmodes.length; i++){try{return new ActiveXObject(activexmodes[i]);}catch(ignore){/*suppress error*/}}}else if (window.XMLHttpRequest){return new XMLHttpRequest();}else{return false;}}

/* Get Value of search */
var searchBoxObj = document.getElementById('searchBox-1'); 

/* The Ajax Request */
var theSearchValue;
var mygetrequest=new ajaxRequest();
mygetrequest.onreadystatechange=function(){
 if (mygetrequest.readyState==4){
  if (mygetrequest.status==200 || window.location.href.indexOf("http")==-1){
    var jsondata=JSON.parse(mygetrequest.responseText), /* retrieve result as an JavaScript object */
      searchData = jsondata.searches,
      i;
    if (searchData.length > 0){
      document.getElementById('result').className = "on";
      output='<ul id="searchResults">';
      for (i=0; i < searchData.length; i++){
        /* The Loop Code */
     }
     output+='</ul>';
   }
   else {
    document.getElementById('result').className = "";
   }

   document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = output;
  }
  else{
   /* alert("An error has occured making the request") */
  }
 }
};

/* With every key press */
var stoppedTyping;
searchBoxObj.onkeyup = function() {

    if (stoppedTyping) { clearTimeout(stoppedTyping);}
    stoppedTyping = setTimeout(function(){
      if (searchBoxObj.value.length > 2){
        theSearchValue = searchBoxObj.value;
        mygetrequest.open("GET", "/asp/lookup.asp?term="+theSearchValue, true);
        mygetrequest.send(null);
      }
    }, 200);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try using jquery to handle the ajax requests and the filling of your result div.
As it is designed to be cross-browser and should support IE correctly (version 2.* of jquery will only support IE from version 8 whereas vers 1.9.* will support IE from version 6)
The code could look like something like that :

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: your_url

})
    .done(function( data ) {
    var jsondata=JSON.parse(data);
    var searchData = jsondata.searches;
     if (searchData.length > 0){
      $('#result').attr("class","on"); //adding the class attr
      output='<ul id="searchResults">';
      for (var i=0; i < searchData.length; i++){
        /* The Loop Code */
     }
     output+='</ul>';
   }
   else {
    $('#result').attr("class","");
   }

$("#result").html(output); //filling the dom with your output string

})
.fail(function() {
    alert( "error" );
  })
```

see jQuery documentation : https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however i cannot use jQuery on this platform. I can use YUI3 however

Comment: Hey ok my bad, I thought it could be a problem with event handling within IE which could have been corrected using jquery ;)